# How to configure port in soap:address in wsdl from the Spring?

Tags: spring, soap, wsdl, cxf

The thing is that Apache CXF takes the location attribute from WSDL file and replaces it with the server's URL, including the port. Is there any way to set the port manually to a specific value?  If it was possible, I would like to do this from Spring...

The relevant part from WSDL:

```
...
<port binding="ns:binding" name="someUrl">
  <soap:address location="http://localhost/url"/>
</port>
...
```

Comment: Are you providing a service or consuming a service?

Comment: @ericacm Providing. The solution is below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the basic endpoint configuration from [Apache CXF website](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html) and added the `publishedEndpointUrl="http://newurl:port/..."` attribute to `jaxws:endpoint` element.